# Серверные многопоточные вычисления

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

У меня стоит такая задача: Нужно реализовать вычислительный сервер на котором будет запущено один или несколько вычислительных потоков. При этом он должен принимать запросы из интернета в которых содержаться данные используемые потоками. Выбор средств такой ASP.NET WCF или облачные вычисления на Azure. При этом в памяти должны постоянно храниться некоторые переменные. А на вебсерверах переменные реинициализируются с каждым новым запросом. Вобщем как реализовать такую работу в бэкграунде на вышеуказанных средствах и можно ли? Если нельзя то как тогда поступить

Comment: Поконкретнее, если можно. Кто и как соединяется, как получает результаты.

Comment: Информации мало, но если я правильно понял вопрос и описание, то реализовать можно :)

Answer (score 1):

Напишите небольшой windows-сервис управляющий потоками и исполняющий вышеуказанные вычисления, да прикрутите к нему управление через web(например через OwinSelfHost)